# Fastest way to check if an array [] exists in a list or in numpy array

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, hashmap, in-operator

I have a list ( grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection)
which is updated and added some elements like as [2,5] ... in it.
I need to check any specific elements and figure out if it exists inside this list.
What is the fast way rather than in-operator? or if I changed the list to the numpy array, how I can find if for instance [3,5] is inside in it or not?
I want to find the fast way rather than below one :

> ```
> Data type; 
> length = 23000
> grains[w].neighbour_Probabale_list=[5,3,6,89,4, 230,...]
> grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection=[[1,5],[2,4],.... [230,156]]
> ```

```
for w in range(length):

  for p in (grains[w].neighbour_Probabale_list):
 
      if w == p or [w, p] in grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection or \
                   [p, w] in grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection \
                    or [w, p] in grains[p].contact_particle_flag_detection \
                    or [p, w] in grains[p].contact_particle_flag_detection:

                     doing some things
```

example:condition will be true if  [1,13914] is in grains[1].contact_particle_flag_detection

contact_particle_flag_detection [[1, 13914], [1, 19122], [1, 11899], [1, 6334], [1, 7034], [1, 16669], [1, 18538], [1, 22284], [1, 3716], [1, 6541], [1, 2765], [1, 21057], [1, 15743], [1, 18778], [1, 1102]]

neighbour_Probabale_list [13914, 19122, 11899, 6334, 7034, 16669, 18538, 22284, 1, 3716, 6541, 2765, 21057, 15743, 18778, 1102]

Comment: This is a very unclear question. Please provide a minimal reproducible example with a sample input and expected output clearly. Thank you.

Comment: In example I asked for what I am looking for. I want to check a specific pairs( in format of array) does exist in the mention list or not. lets say to find in a list or an array. In_operator take much time. I want to optimize the speed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer since your question doesn't include a sample of the data. But I assumed that your data looks something like the following below -

```
length = 6
pp = [5,6,7,8,9,0]
kk = [[1,5],[4,4],[2,6],[3,2]]
```

pp is the grains[w].neighbour_Probabale_list

kk is the grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection

You can use a list comprehension for a fast implementation

```
[True if [w,p] in kk else False for p in pp for w in range(length)]
```

Replace the True and False with what you wanna do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.p and w are determined in the loop in advance. so I need to count w and p. Also, In-operator takes much time when the list elements are so much in grains[w].contact_particle_flag_detection.

Comment: could you edit your question with a sample for each of the lists and an expected output.. its really difficult to understand what you mean without any reference. thanks.

Comment: I did some clarification. Thanks